# Не считывает команду на discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.messages = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"We have logged in as {bot.user}")


@bot.command()
async def my_ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, you have been pinged!')


bot.run('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN')  # токен у меня стоит
```

Сверху кинул код с GPT.

Код взял только для того чтобы проверить в чем проблема
Так вот:делаю свой код на discord.py, добавил в цельный код команду `my_ping` в которой бот должен пинговать (отмечать) автора сообщения,когда сделал код - команда не работает, при этом в консоле ничего не происходит.

Бот удачно заходит и логинится, но при написании `.my_ping` в чате ничего не выдает, и в консоли тоже ни слова про это, в общем просто не считывает команду, ошибку не выдает, перед этим пробовал сделать через `@bot.event` - все также, при этом делал по видео, где у мужика все получалось и автора пинговало, не понимаю почему у меня не получается при том что код нормальный.

Answer (score 0):

Не хватает `message content intent`.
Выставляете галочку здесь (зайдите в [портал разработчиков](https://discord.com/developers/applications), нажмите на вашего бота, перейдите во вкладку `Bot`):
[image: скрин]
В коде:

```py
# intents.dm_messages = True # разкомментируйте, если хотите получать сообщения в ЛС бота
intents.guild_messages = True # сообщения на серверах
intents.message_content = True # содержимое сообщения
```